# Is there a way to set per_process_gpu_memory_fraction tensorflow.js (.JS!)?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Knowing that you can set the max. memory amount for GPUs for Tensorflow,
I wonder how can I prevent tensorflow**.js** from using all my gpu ram. I didn't found anything in the API documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet. Currently you can only select to register the tensorflow backend by using `tf.setBackend` which will use all the available gpu.

- use tensorflow backend by using

```js
tf.setBackend('tensorflow')
```

- use webgl or cpu in the brower by using

```js
tf.setBackend('cpu')

tf.setBackend('webgl') // if using tfjs with the browser
```